# Accessing HttpConnection in Java ME application

Tags: java-me, httpconnection

i want to access the URL in `Java ME` Application ,i am getting the Code for `HttpConnection`(html code) but i want the output as we see in browser, is it ok if my app get redirected in native browser or it will be better if can I see the output in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to redirected in native browser,if you want to permently out of application because when you redirect then your midlet going to be paused state. if you want show your result same like web browser then you have do remove html tags from it and you have to design your canvas for your result. 
thanks